# Could the Vue app catch the child's emitted event in the js?

Tags: vue.js

I am the new to the Vuejs.
Normally `Vue` uses the `event` when sending data to the parent.
For example,

```
Vue.component('child', {
 template: `
  <div class="myitem">
     <button v-on:click="senddata()">
        Send Data
     </button>
 </div>`,
   methods:{
      senddata:function(){
         this.$emit('data', 'testdata');
      }
   }
 })
```

And then by using 'child', in the parent component or app.

```
<child v-on:data="eventHandler" ref="child"></child>
```

In the parent methods , there is a `eventHandler` to process the data sent from child.
If the `child` component emits the event `data`, the `eventHandler` would be called.

```
methods: {
    eventHandler: function (data) {
       console.log('received data: ' + data);   
    }
}
```

This works well.
But I want to add the `eventHandler` in the code.

```
this.$refs.child.data().then(function(data){
   //According to the data..., the app want to process data...

});
```

The code like the above is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to add the eventHandler in the code.

Then you'll need to use the [Programmatic Event Listeners API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners); in particular [`$on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on):

```es6
mounted() {
  this.$refs.child.$on('data', this.eventHandler);
},

methods: {
  eventHandler(data) {
    ...
  }
},
```

In this specific example, you would need to do it in the `mounted` hook since the child component wouldn't be created yet in the `created` hook.

Comment: The vue component could be added dynmically like `this.$refs.parent.add(child)` (Sorry,This is not relative to my question.)?

Comment: Mainly I want to add ,remove all component in the js code. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot (and should not) programmatically insert and remove components like that. I cannot provide a suitable answer because I need to know what it is you are trying to achieve. You should ask a new question.

Comment: Simply I want to show the different modal dialog according to the condition.